# Find percentage increase from previous year

Tags: mysql

To be honest, i don't know where to start with this script. I can produce results which show me, per month, the total revenue of sales, from the sales table.

The following script:

```
SELECT coalesce(date_format(TRANSACTION_DATE, '%M'), 'Grand Total') AS MONTH,
ROUND(SUM(SALES_AMOUNT),2) TOTAL
FROM SALES
WHERE YEAR(TRANSACTION_DATE) = 2018
GROUP BY month
```

Results: (which are fine & work out correctly)

```
Month   Total
January 45163.22
February    34531.15
March   44194.98
April   30826.68
May 39016.04
June    37284.25
July    37640.08
August  39703.85
September   34958.94
October 34447.61
November    39161.9
December    36986.16
```

However, I want to produce the below results...i.e Jan with NULL, and Feb has a difference of -10632.07, equating to decrease of 23.54%

```
        Difference  Percentage Increase/Decrease
January 45163.22        
February    34531.15    -10632.07   -23.54
March   44194.98    9663.83 27.99
April   30826.68    -13368.3    -30.25
May 39016.04    8189.36 26.57
June    37284.25    -1731.79    -4.44
July    37640.08    355.83  0.95
August  39703.85    2063.77 5.48
September   34958.94    -4744.91    -11.95
October 34447.61    -511.33 -1.46
November    39161.9 4714.29 13.69
December    36986.16    -2175.74    -5.56
```

Hope that makes sense, and if anyone can help me out, that would be great.

Thank you

Comment: What MySQL version?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a join

```
    select a.MONTH, a.TOTAL, a.TOTAL - b.TOTAL,  ((a.TOTAL - b.TOTAL)/ a.TOTAL )*100
    from (

    SELECT coalesce(date_format(TRANSACTION_DATE, '%M'), 'Grand Total') AS MONTH,
    ROUND(SUM(SALES_AMOUNT),2) TOTAL
    FROM SALES
    WHERE YEAR(TRANSACTION_DATE) = 2018
    GROUP BY month
     ) a
    inner  join (
    SELECT coalesce(date_format(TRANSACTION_DATE, '%M'), 'Grand Total') AS MONTH,
    ROUND(SUM(SALES_AMOUNT),2) TOTAL
    FROM SALES
    WHERE YEAR(TRANSACTION_DATE) = 2017
    GROUP BY month
     ) b ON a.month = b.month
```

Answer (score 0):

By joining SALES to itself on the month, and limiting the 2nd SALES to the previous year, you will have the matching months for the two years.

```
SELECT 
    coalesce(date_format(a.`TRANSACTION_DATE`, '%M'), 'Grand Total') AS `MONTH`,
    ROUND(SUM(a.`SALES_AMOUNT`),2) AS `TOTAL_2018`,
    ROUND(SUM(b.`SALES_AMOUNT`),2) AS `TOTAL_2017`,
    ROUND(SUM(a.`SALES_AMOUNT`),2) - ROUND(SUM(b.`SALES_AMOUNT`),2) AS `Difference`,
    ROUND((ROUND(SUM(a.`SALES_AMOUNT`),2) - ROUND(SUM(b.`SALES_AMOUNT`),2)) / ROUND(SUM(b.`SALES_AMOUNT`),2),2) AS `Percentage_Difference`
FROM `SALES` a
JOIN `SALES` b
ON YEAR(b.`TRANSACTION_DATE`) = YEAR(a.`TRANSACTION_DATE`) - 1 AND 
    MONTH(a.`TRANSACTION_DATE`) = MONTH(b.`TRANSACTION_DATE`)
WHERE YEAR(a.`TRANSACTION_DATE`) = 2018
GROUP BY a.coalesce(date_format(a.`TRANSACTION_DATE`, '%M'), 'Grand Total')
ORDER BY a.coalesce(date_format(a.`TRANSACTION_DATE`, '%M'), 'Grand Total');
```

Note that by removing the WHERE clause and adding the year to the group by and order by clauses, you could produce a report for multiple years.